# How to end a python subprocess with no return?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm working on a BCP wrapper method in Python, but have run into an issue invoking the command with subprocess.

As far as I can tell, the BCP command doesn't return any value or indication that it has completed outside of what it prints to the terminal window, which causes subprocess.call or subprocess.run to hang while they wait for a return.

subprocess.Popen allows a manual .terminate() method, but I'm having issues getting the table to write afterwards.

The bcp command works from the command line with no issues, it loads data from a source csv according to a .fmt file and writes an error log file. My script is able to dismount the file from log path, so I would consider the command itself irrelevant and the question to be around the behavior of the subprocess module.

This is what I'm trying at the moment:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(bcp_command)
    try:
        path = Path(log_path)
        sleep_counter = 0
        while path.is_file() == False and sleep_counter < 16:
            sleep(1)
            sleep_counter +=1
    finally:
        
        
        process.terminate()
    self.datacommand = datacommand
```

My idea was to check that the error log file has been written by the bcp command as a way to tell that the process had finished, however while my script no longer freezes with this, and the files are apparently being successfully written and dismounted later on in the script. The script terminates in less than the 15 seconds that the sleep loop would use to end it as well.

When the process froze my Spyder shell (and Idle, so it's not the IDE), I could force terminate it by closing the console itself and it would write to the server at least.

However it seems like by using the .terminate() the command isn't actually writing anything to the server.

I checked if a dumb 15 second time-out (it takes about 2 seconds to do the BCP with this data) would work as well, in case it was writing an error log before the load finished.

Still resulted in an empty table on SQL server.

How can I get subprocess to execute a command without hanging?

Comment: This sounds vaguely unreproducible, and hard to diagnose without further details. My first speculation would be that the command does something differently when invoked without a `tty`, and that it's printing something to standard error which you are not noticing. Can you please [edit] to explain in more detail what this BCP command is and how to obtain it, and probably also the result of `bcp </dev/null >/dev/null` on the command line, or some other appreciable approximation of running with stdin and stdout disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems to be a more general issue about calling helper functions with Popen

as seen here:
https://github.com/dropbox/pyannotate/issues/67

I was able to fix the hanging issue by changing it to:

```
subprocess.Popen(bcp_command, close_fds = True)
```